# How to remove functions in dictionary while checking for repeated elements to add or not

Tags: python

I wrote this code to remove duplicate elements and tried to use `remove` when finding duplicates while adding elements to dictionary. Can anyone please explain how this `remove` works in this context because I am unclear at times how remove functions with a dictionary. Small part of code is below.

```
def remove_duplicates(a = [1,1,3,4,5,6,6,6,6,121,45,6,3,4]):
    b = []
    mapped = {}
    for i in a:
        try:
            mapped.get(i)
            mapped.remove(i)
        except:
            mapped[i] = i
    for j in mapped:
        b.append(j)
    return b
```

output is `[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 121, 45]`

Comment: I don't believe that remove is a method on dict

Answer (score 2):

The answer is `remove` doesn't work, because `dict`s don't have a `remove` method. So you'd always get an `AttributeError`, but by catching and ignoring *all* exceptions, you never see it, making:

```
    try:
        mapped.get(i)
        mapped.remove(i)
    except:
        mapped[i] = i
```

equivalent to a slower version of:

```
    mapped[i] = i
```

(except if you're unlucky, it might also silence critical exceptions like `KeyboardInterrupt`s too).

This whole function is kind of ridiculous mind you. The same behavior could be achieved with:

```
def remove_duplicates(a = [1,1,3,4,5,6,6,6,6,121,45,6,3,4]):
    return list(dict.fromkeys(a))
```

Traditionally, it would be `return list(set(a))`, but [since 3.6 and higher provide ordered `dict`s](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-compactdict), using `dict.fromkeys` means you preserve the order in which values were first observed, while still discarding duplicates (on 3.5 and earlier, `set` vs `dict.fromkeys` won't matter; `dict.fromkeys` might be a little slower or use a little more memory, but the behavior will be roughly the same).

Comment: Blanket excepts are rarely a good idea in Python. Great point.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove duplicates from a list and don't care about order, a simple way is to use `set`.

```
removed_duplicates = set(my_list)
```

Where `my_list` is the list you want to de-dedupe. A side-effect of this is that you'll lose order, but that may not matter for you.

This is basically what you are doing, except you are constructing a map from each element to itself, which is equivalent to a set.

Comment: The original code *won't* lose order on 3.6 or higher, thanks to using `dict`s (which became ordered as an [implementation detail in 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-compactdict), and as [a language guarantee in 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#summary-release-highlights)). `list(dict.fromkeys(my_list))` would preserve order while deduping the same way the OP's code does though.

Comment: I was trying to avoid methods and do with as much basic logic as possible, hence came with this idea. Thanks for that.